# Concurrent Session Control - Spring Security

Tags: spring, session, spring-security

HI I am trying to implement Spring Security: Concurrent Session Control to limit one session at a time. I see that I only need

```
<http>
  ...
   <session-management>
     <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" />
   </session-management>
</http>
```

I get this from the reference http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-config . The problem that I am facing is that i get this error saying, "Configuration problem: No AuthenticationEntryPoint could be established. Please make sure you have a login mechanism configured through the namespace (such as form-login) or specify a custom AuthenticationEntryPoint with the 'entry-point-ref' attribute" I do not need to use a login page in the configuration here. I saw other posts, but I cannot find a solution to this problem. Please help me with a solution here. I will post my code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-    mvc.xsd">

<security:http>
    <security:session-management>
        <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
    </security:session-management>
</security:http>
```

Comment: how do you authenticate users ?

Comment: Concurrent session control is per user not for the whole server/application.

Comment: I am using a bean   <bean id="signinAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <constructor-arg name="loginFormUrl" value="/signin.s2"/>
        <property name="forceHttps" value="false"/>
    </bean>

Comment: you should switch that to the security namespace http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/reference/ns-config.html#ns-form-and-basic something's not getting wired correctly