# Spring mvc 4 Concurrent Session Control

Tags: java, spring, session, authentication

I have read on this site and docs on setting concurrent session control which I did not know Spring handles so well.

Examples: 
[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21193538/concurrent-session-control-spring-security)
[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19319849/spring-security-3-1-session-concurrency-control-not-working-why?rq=1)
amongst others....

However I cannot find how to do do so programatically (not application context) in Spring version 4 controller (spring 4 - annotated).

```
<http>
  ...
   <session-management>
     <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" />
   </session-management>
</http>
```

I have read about ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy, ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy, CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy but have not been able to implement. What I am trying to do is make sure a user can only log-in once and if someone else logs in with same username it give them an error page.

Appreciate any help or advice...

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have in my app. This gives an error to any attempt to login if there is a valid session

...security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-  exceeded="true"..

Comment: I mentioned NOT in XML -> only programatically.

Answer (score 0):

hopefully you can do this by implementing `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionBindingListener` interface and register it as a `ServletContext` [listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#addListener(java.lang.Class)) through java configuration.

Refer: [How to invalidate another session when an user is logged in twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372311/how-to-invalidate-an-user-session-when-he-logs-twice-with-the-same-credentials/2372990#2372990)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am trying to keep out the new user not kick out the original logged-in user.

Comment: Of course that is up to you, If you find that the same user trying to login again either you can invalidate newly created session or existing one.